# How to trim a bunch of open curves with a closed shape in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, clipping-mask

Suppose I've drawn a bunch of open curves like these:

[image]

Then I add a closed shape (circle) on top of them:

[image]

I know that I can use a *clipping mask* to only show the parts of the curves inside of the shape:

[image]

But I would like to "apply" this clipping mask, in the sense that I'd like to literal cut each curve by the outline of the closed shape and only keep the parts that remain inside. I can use the scissors tool to do this manually and then delete.

[image]

But is there an automatic way to do this?

I've tried all combinations of the pathfinder tools but cannot get this result.

(I'm also open to non Illustrator solutions so long as the output is a set of vector graphics curves).

**Edit:** I'd really like to do this *on the strokes* rather than resorting to outline/expanding the open curves first. In that case, I could use Outline Stroke, then Make Compound Path, then Intersect to get:

[image]

But this results in filled regions shaped according to the original width of the strokes. They're no longer editable as open strokes.

Answer (score 5):

One method would be to just click the **Outline** button on the **Pathfinder Panel**, reapply the stroke, then remove unwanted pieces.

[image]

This keeps the strokes as strokes rather than expanding them. If you are okay with expanding the strokes, you can expand everything then Pathfinder -> Merge and then delete unwanted pieces. Or adjust pathfinder options to remove unpainted objects (In the panel menu), then expand and crop and reapply fills.

Or you could select it all and use the **Shape Builder Tool** with the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key held down to drag across pieces you want removed.....[image]

Comment: I'm having a hard time repeating your result. If I select everything and then click PathFinder > Crop only the circle is left...

Comment: Are you certain you're clicking the crop button? And crop *after* making the clipping mask. Or... have you changed the pathfinder options in the pathfinder panel menu? (If you have the first method here may not work).

Comment: Meanwhile, the Shape Builder Tool worked! but still a lot of clicking and searching if the shape is more complicated than a circle.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately i don't think there's an easy 2-step processes. Anything is going to require several clicks to either select or delete things.

Comment: Here's an animation of trying to crop, also showing my options: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYVa9.gif

Comment: @AlecJacobson **My Fault** I posted "Crop" button, but I meant the **Outline** button (and that is the button clicked in the animation above). I corrected the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that works now though it seems to close up all of the open curves. (The same comment about needing to manually select and remove everything applies)

Comment: Yeah, there's not really a feature that's going to be simple if you want the strokes to remain strokes. If the strokes can be expanded it does get a bit more straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

The Shape Builder Tool (as demonstrated by Metis) does a pretty nice job... But what if you have an older version of AI which doesn't have Shaper?

Here is a dirty way to do this but it does the trick (if you don't need the circle 'crop' to be 100% perfect):

- Lock the circle layer (we'll just use it as a guide) and select all of your loose paths
- Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to activate the Eraser Tool and click+drag over the circle
- Press the <kbd>Q</kbd> key to activate the Lasso Tool and drag a selection around those parts you wish to keep
- Go to Select > Inverse and hit the <kbd>Del</kbd> key, then get rid of the circle

A demonstration:

[image: Stupid Illustrator makes this way too hard]

Or... if you have lots of room to play with – just make your Eraser bigger and wipe them out completely in one step:

[image: MY WHAT A BIG ERASER YOU HAVE THERE]

~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~

**Update:**

I found another option for those without the Shape Builder Tool; an Illustrator plugin which can accomplish this with more precision, using just one tool:

The Hatchet Tool ([available here](http://rj-graffix.com/downloads/plugins/))

[image: Cutting Tools: Hatchet Tool description]

Here it is in action:

[image: Hatchet Tool demo]

Answer (score 0):

From your picture #2, if all squiggles are Grouped and on the same layer and the blue circle is a closed path, than select circle and squiggles and use Pathfinder>Outline.

Ungroup and remove whatever remains of the circle shape and squiggle tails that fell outside the circle and the result will be the portions of squiggles within the circle.

Comment: That gives me a different result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W21k.png

I'd also like to avoid having to do tasks like "select everything inside the shape" since in general the shape will be very complex.

Comment: I'm sorry, i should have studied it more (or at least tried it). Can the paths be expanded? I was able to accomplish it with Divide after expanding, but then the squiggle paths are no longer editable.